# Fluent Nhibernate Mapping for Sql Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

i am using Fluent Nhibernate in asp.net mvc3 with c#

i am working in following way to generate and map a class

**Mapping**

```
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
using Com.Web.Domain;

   namespace Com.Web.Mapping
      {
         public class CompanyMap : ClassMap<Company>
        {
             public CompanyMap()
            {
               Id(x => x.id);
               Map(x => x.Name);
              }
          }
       }
```

**Class**

```
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System;

      namespace Com.Web.Domain
      {

          public class Company
         {

          public virtual int id { get; set; }
          public virtual string Name{get;set}

           }

        }
```

and in configuration file

```
  private static void InitializeSessionFactory()
    {

       _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                          .ConnectionString(local)

            )
            .Mappings(m =>
                      m.FluentMappings
                          .AddFromAssemblyOf<Company>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg)
            .Create(false, false))  // this is intentionally set false , bcz i dont want to regenerate table when application starts every time 
            .BuildSessionFactory();


    }
```

now problem come i create a view in sql looks like this

**Sql View**

```
CREATE VIEW [FeaturedCompanies] AS

   SELECT COUNT(Company.id) As Count FROM Company
   WHERE Name='Alias'
```

i want to use this view in my code as a like i am using but how can i do that , i searched alot but found nothing on google

Pleas help me out and thanks in advance

**what is tried so far**

**Class**

```
public class FeaturedCompany
{
    public virtual int id { get; set; }
    public virtual int name { get; set; }
    public virtual int count { get; set; }
}
```

**Mapping**

```
public class FeaturedCompanyMap : ClassMap<FeaturedCompany>
  {
 public FeaturedCompanyMap()
 {
    Table("FeaturedCompanies");
    ReadOnly();
   Id(x => x.id);
   Map(x => x.name);
   Map(x => x.count);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Views are mapped the same way tables are mapped except that you should put `Readonly()` in the mapping to prevent accidently writing to it. Example:

```
public class FeaturedCompanyMap : ClassMap<FeaturedCompany>
{
    public FeaturedCompanyMap ()
    {
       Table("FeaturedCompanies");
       ReadOnly();

       Id(x => x.Id);
       Map(x => x.Name);
       Map(x => x.Count);
    }
}
```

Update: to get the counts

```
var results = session.Query<FeaturedCompany>().Where(filter).List();

foreach(var row in results.Select(r => "Alias: " + r.Name + "  Occurence: " + r.Count))
{
    // print row to screen
}
```

Comment: but how will i can get counts ( i mean the result of my view in razor view or c# ) ?

Comment: see my updated question , what i tried my application runs fine but i don't know how to get counts in c#

Comment: Hi @Martin, I am trying to use view with nhibernate, I did mapping as following code snippet. But query to bellow object return nothing.

[Class(NameType = typeof(LeadReviewDetail), Table = "vw_lead_review_detail", Lazy = false, Schema = "affiliate")]
    public class LeadReviewDetail
    {
        [Id(Name = "LeadEventId", Column = "lead_event_id", UnsavedValue = "0")]
        [Generator(1, Class = "assigned")]
        public virtual int? LeadEventId { get; set; }
        [Property(Column = "addition_input_value")]
        public virtual string AdditionInputValue { get; set; }
    }