# Fluent NHibernate multiple table with the same schema

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have 100 tables with the same schema. What is the best solution with Fluent NHibernate for this situation? I mean what mapping(s) I should create? Thanks in advance!
See pict.:

[image]

PS. Every table contains a really huge amount of data.

Comment: PPS I need query to all that tables as if they are a single table.

Comment: do you only need to read from those tables, or do you want to write data as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **ONLY** want to map all the tables for reading purposes, you can do it creating an SQL view that performs a `UNION ALL` query over all your tables.

Then, just map your SQL view as you map a single table.

Take a look into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12742908/982431) for a previous question (and similar too).